# Pip, packages and Python3

Tags: python-3.x, pip

i'm trying to install pydot in python3 and i came up with some questions:

The packages referenced by pip3.3 are the same referenced by pip2.7 or there is a different repository for the packages ?

How does all the packaging/distribution work in python ?

What should i do for installing pydot through pip ?
Actually the creator say that python3 is not supported, but pydot is listed in pip3.3
A fork of pydot (https://bitbucket.org/prologic/pydot) working on Python3 exists, why it is not listed in pip?

Can I install pydot through pip?

Answer (score 0):

Almost all package/program distribution in python is done with distutils. This is very good documented in the [python documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/distutils.html#module-distutils).

To your specific problem: pip usually searches the PyPI for the package and then downloads a distribution of that package. Most often this is a source-package and needs to be byte-compiled. If that succeeds the package is most probably compatible to the python version you're using, if it's not you will most probably get SyntaxErrors or something like that.
As i know PyPI has no other, ultimate-sure version classifiers.

So the most sure way to tell if the package is compatible, is to try to install it and then try if it works.